# How can I disable auto_prepend in specific folders using htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm using auto_prepend on my website, however I don't want it to be used in every folder.  How can I stop php from auto_prepending a file within certain folders using .htaccess? (It doesn't have to be .htacces, I can use any other method but I thought I'd start with .htaccess)

ps - I'm using the auto_prepend in php.ini to set the auto_prepend

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In a `.htaccess` file, you can use this to define a specific file that will be auto-prepended, in a directory :

```
php_value auto_prepend_file "prepend.php"
```

So, I suppose you could use this to de-activate auto-prepending in a directory :

```
php_value auto_prepend_file none
```

Note I am using the special value "`none`", as explained in the documentation of [`auto_prepend_file`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file) :

> The special value *none*  disables
>   auto-prepending.

Comment: Ha. geez I was using "none" (with quotes) and it wasn't working so I moved on to try other things and eventually post here.  That worked perfectly. thx for helping out a n00b!