# Reset htacces for sub-folders

Tags: .htaccess

I have a htacces file in my root folder with some basic code in it. But I want that all those instructions get ignored in the directory "voxelforum.com". How can I achive this?

Thanks!

Comment: Might be interested in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788088/how-can-i-disable-auto-prepend-in-specific-folders-using-htaccess

Answer (score 19):

Oddly, you may first need to turn off rewrite and then put it on again

Put a `.htaccess` file in the subfolder and add these 2 lines:

```
RewriteEngine Off
RewriteEngine On
```

Add your rewrite rules below

---

This worked for me whereas simply adding `RewriteEngine On` did not.

Comment: This was the case for me as well. I need both Off and On.

Comment: Glad it helped though don't understand why the trigger off was required first.  Strange one, I still have my .htaccess this way :/

Answer (score 10):

It depends on what rules you want to override:

If you want to disable rewrite rules, then you can put a .htaccess file in the subfolder that contains `RewriteEngine On`, and the rules for the parent folder will be disabled (technically, replaced).

Similarly, if you want to disable authentication for a subfolder, you can create a .htaccess that contains `Satisfy Any`.

.htaccess rules cascade upwards, so Apache will look for a .htaccess file in the current folder and use the rules for it, then check the parent folder, etc.

Comment: I'll try this one. Seems logical.

Comment: I started doing all my htaccess rules in my conf file and eliminated htaccess files.  I believe there is a performance boost to be had doing this as well.

Comment: @MichaelDeMutis That's correct, for maximum performance benefit don't forget to disable htaccess files altogether so Apache doesn't even look for them. I would say this is an option that's not available to everyone, though, as not every developer deploys to an environment that they control.

Comment: @KevinMackay What is the procedure to disable it completely from Apache?

Comment: @MichaelDeMutis You can disable htaccess completely by setting `AllowOverride` to `None` - see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html

Answer (score 1):

Remove your htaccess from your root folder and move it in your subfolders.
As far as I know there is no way to disable htaccess for the root folder.

EDIT: check [AllowOverride](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride)

Comment: But I want my htacces in my root folder (main website) but I don't want it in my sub-folder (secondary website).

Comment: But you're saying it isn't possible?

Comment: Ah, sorry, not sure about that but check the AllowOverride directive

Comment: AllowOverride is used to determine what directives are allowed within a .htaccess file - eg, if you put "AllowOverride None" in your apache configuration, .htaccess files would be disabled completely. Though the name suggests otherwise, it doesn't affect whether .htaccess files can override each other.
That said, you could put <Directory /path/to/subfolder>AllowOverride None</Directory> in your apache/vhost configuration, which _might_ disable the parent folder's .htaccess rules. It's certainly worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

Put a .htaccess file in the subfolder and add this line only:

RewriteEngine On