# .htaccess url rewriting and conflict with existing file name

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

## Question:

I need to redirect `edit/profil` to `edit.php?p=profil`, but the `p` parameter is not send to `edit.php`. Do you know what could be the reason for that?

## Details:

The server is a shared server, so I don't have access to the Apache config files.
My folder is located in `/fr/intranet` and contains two files : `edit.php` and `.htaccess`.
The content of `edit.php` is very simple :

```
<?php
  echo '<pre>';
  echo "This is edit.php\n";
  var_dump($_GET);
  echo '</pre>';
?>
```

And the content of `.htaccess` is the following:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /fr/intranet/

RewriteRule ^edit/profil/?$ edit.php?p=profil [L]
RewriteRule ^test/profil/?$ edit.php?p=profil [L]
```

When I load `/fr/intranet/test/profil`, the PHP script displays :

```
This is edit.php
array(1) {
  ["p"]=>
  string(6) "profil"
}
```

When I load `/fr/intranet/edit/profil` (this is the reason I post here), the PHP script displays :

```
This is edit.php
array(0) {
}
```

## What I have tested so far

### Parent .htaccess conflict

There is a Wordpress installed in the /fr/ folder with a .htaccess. I wondered if it could have some rewriting rules in conflict with mine. It should not, as my htaccess have the priority. Besides there are no rules that may produce the behavior I encounter:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /fr/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

### The QSA flag

I know about the QSA flag, but it's not the problem here. If I have understood correctly, the QSA flag looks for the entire URL (including GET parameters) when redirecting, but I don't have GET parameters in the requested URL. Adding it doesn't change the behavior anyway.

### Creating test.php

If I create a file named `/fr/intranet/test.php` with the following content:

```
<?php
  echo '<pre>';
  echo "This is test.php\n"
  var_dump($_GET);
  echo '</pre>';
?>
```

and if I load `/fr/intranet/test/profil`, then I get the following output:

```
This is test.php
array(0) {
}
```

Also, if I remove the `.htaccess` file, loading `/fr/intranet/test` displays the output of `/fr/intranet/test.php`.

Everything behave like there were an hidden rules more or less like this one:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^([^/]+).*$ $1.php [L]
```

### RewriteEngine off/on

I have found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23227385/3174124) that switching RewriteEngine off then on in the `.htaccess` file may disable parent rewriting rules. But it didn't solve my problem.

Comment: Try disabling MultiViews (`Options -MultiViews`), it is often the one to blame in such situations.

Comment: @CBroe it works. I have been stuck for hours because of this options I have never heard of. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try disabling MultiViews (`Options -MultiViews`), it is often the one to blame in such situations.

(For a more detailed explanation of what MultiViews does, see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_negotiation.html#multiviews. This often interferes with rewriting when a file with the same name [minus extension] exists as the “fake” path segment one tries to rewrite.)