# htaccess - redirect non www to www but leave subdomain out

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I got this code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

so every page on `bla.com` get redirected to `www.bla.com`

But the problem I got mobile version inside `bla.com/m/` which is for `m.bla.com`

Now when I got to `m.bla.com` I get redirected to `www.m.bla.com`

How to prevent this?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=redirect+non+www+to+www+but+leave+subdomain+out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|m)\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: It's still the same :(

Comment: Not even http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12849703/reset-htacces-for-sub-folders works wtf is this crap

Comment: Clear your cache or try with other browser