# PHP append and prepend in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

In every single one of my `php` files I have to do:

```
<?php require_once('file.php'); ?>
```

I've been doing a Google research and found that I could use the `.htaccess` to append or prepend any php file or any other files I need in each of my other files like this:

```
php_value auto_prepend_file "/real/path/to/file/file.php"
php_value auto_append_file "/real/path/to/file/file.php"
```

I'm a novice and have not yet played around too much with the `.htaccess`. Also, I've read that messing with `.htaccess` can wreak havoc to my website, I haven't tried it out.

My question here is this. I also have jQuery files in my application, if the `.htaccess` is going to append/prepend the `file.php` in each and every file, without even trying it out I know it's going to include my stylesheets, my log files, etc. Is there a way make exclusions to files where I don't want `file.php` to be appended/prepended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can disable it in specific folders. [How can I disable auto_prepend in specific folders using htaccess?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788088/how-can-i-disable-auto-prepend-in-specific-folders-using-htaccess)

If you want to conditionally disable it in certain files, you can have a conditional statement in your append.php where it doesn't echo whatever it is that it normally does, if the filename matches a certain condition
You can use  `_____FILE_____` directive to get the current file, and you can have a condition check

```
<?php
if(__FILE__!="..yourfile..")
{
?>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="...">
...

<?php
}
?>
```

and so on