# wanting to add urls to robots.txt via htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, robots.txt

I have a WP site and am currently redirecting several links through .htaccess via a plugin and would like to add the original redirected links to robots.txt via the same htaccess file.

Here is the example redirects in htaccess

Redirect /probing-pre-attack-1/ /send-somwhere/
Redirect /probing-pre-attack-2/ /send-somwhere/ 
Redirect /probing-pre-attack-3/ /send-somwhere/

This is what I am wishing to input into the WP robots.txt

User-agent: *
Disallow: /probing-pre-attack-1/ 
Disallow: /probing-pre-attack-2/ 
Disallow: /probing-pre-attack-3/

Comment: I edited my answer. I think this might solve your problem ! Please mark as solved if it was correct.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do this with a WP-plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/kb-robotstxt/

[edit]

I think you do not want anybody to use the folder /probing-pre-attack-1/ etc, neither do you want the search engines. You could just password-protect these folders. More information about this: http://www.htaccesstools.com/articles/password-protection/

Another solution, is displayed here: [PHP append and prepend in htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17016629/php-append-and-prepend-in-htaccess), where you can append a file to another file. I think this is what you are looking for !

Comment: thanks but I would much prefer to do this where the redirects occur so thought I would ask how it was done. that plugin has not been updated in over 2 yrs so another reason to do the small stuff in house.