# How can I unconditionally apply an auto_prepend in /etc/php.ini?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

On our Apache server, it turns out that an [`auto_prepend_file`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file) specified in `/etc/php.ini` (and intended to be applied to all PHP files on the server) [is disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788088/how-can-i-disable-auto-prepend-in-specific-folders-using-htaccess) by any `auto_prepend_file` statement in `.htaccess`.

I am happy to allow `auto_prepend_file` statements in `.htaccess`, but in that case I still need the one in `/etc/php.ini` to take effect as well.

How to achieve this?

Comment: If you only wan't to use an override for a specific file I guess you could use `<FilesMatch "index\.php">php_value auto_prepend_file "/dir/path/yourfile.php" </FilesMatch>`

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to specify inside your apache config a `php_admin_value`

**From [PHP.net](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php):**

> Sets the value of the specified directive. This can not be used in .htaccess files. Any directive type set with php_admin_value can not be overridden by .htaccess or ini_set(). To clear a previously set value use none as the value.

```
php_admin_value auto_prepend_file "/path/to/your/file.php"
```

This will prevent any user to override it from a `.htaccess` file. Since it's not possible to precise two paths, you won't be able to "add" a path from a htaccess, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to break the users' own `auto_prepend_file`s.